# SpringBoot doesn't recognize a mysql database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've tried to create a crud using springboot and in execution time it doesn't update a database with the entities created.
I have my database created,and xampp server active

That's my code
Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="emp_name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column
    private String salary;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, String salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Application.propierties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a relatively recent version of Spring Boot and MySQL you may want to try using the following dialect to see if this helps:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8InnoDBDialect has been deprecated for a while.

If the above doesn't work can you give us a little more context as to what versions of Spring Boot and MySQL you are using? Are you getting any errors or anything in the logs when the application starts up?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest double check your schema name and the entity you defined.
You can define the Table annotation of your entity like this to make sure it match with the correct schema in your database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {....}
```

**If above doesn't solve your problem**. You could try another approach to make sure your application and database is connected and able to look up the correct schema for data.

1. Create a corresponding repository interface by extending the JpaRepository interface provided by Spring Data JPA:

> ```
> public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
> ```

2. **Create a REST controller class to define your CRUD operations. You can use annotations like @RestController, @GetMapping, @PutMapping, and etc. For example:**

> ```
> @RestController
> @RequestMapping("/employees")
> public class EmployeeController{
>
> @Autowired
> private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
>
>
> @GetMapping("/{id}")
> public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
>     Optional<Employee> employee= employeeRepository.findById(id);
>     return product.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
> }
>
>
> @PutMapping("/{id}")
> public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Employee updatedEmployee) {
>     if (!employeeRepository.existsById(id)) {
>         return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
>     }
>     updatedEmployee.setId(id);
>     Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(updatedEmployee);
>     return ResponseEntity.ok(savedEmployee);
> }
> }
> ```

Build and run your Spring Boot application.
Use a tool like Postman or a web browser to test your CRUD operations controller.
If things still not coming up for you, try to debug the application log for clue to troubleshoot. HTH.